# On the union step add a group by and take the max shipment date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please help me as where to add the group by in the below query and get the max shipment date so that i get one headered record so it does not double up later in the proc?

```
    SELECT HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date
    FROM HEADERINFO
    UNION
    SELECT HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date
    FROM HEADERINFO2
```

Comment: Give an example of your desire output. By looking to your input its not clear. If you want to have group by then have derived table and apply group by, just a thought. Need more info here.

Comment: You want the one record from your query with the newest shipment date? Can there be ties (two records with the same date)? What to do then?

Comment: What is your DBMS? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ... Please tag it.

Comment: Actually in the existing SP there is no Actual Shipment Date in the UNION Query.
 So i am trying to add the shipment date with UNION but by doing this my output is
 getting changed i.e values in 2 columns in the output are nearly getting doubled which should not happen.
 So i thought of adding a group by clause and taking the max shipment date so that the counts does
 not get doubled. But the below query fails to execute

Comment: select HEADER_ID,max(Actual_Shipment_Date) As [Actual_Shipment_Date]
from (SELECT HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date into #TMPHEADERID FROM HEADERINFO  
 UNION
SELECT HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date FROM HEADERINFO2 ) TE group by HEADER_ID

Comment: You are saying that so far you only selected Header IDs and because of using UNION you got no duplicates. But now you want to add the shipment date and you suddenly get the Header IDs multifold, because you get one result record per date. Therefore you only want the maximum shipping date per Header ID. Yes?

Comment: And you are doing all this in some stored procedure in your DBMS. But what DBMS is this? You haven't answered this. You must know whether you are using SQL Server or MySQL or Oracle or whatever, but we don't.

Comment: This all i am doing in a store procedure in SQL server (T-SQL)

Comment: Okay. I've added the tag for you. I don't know stored procedures in SQL Server, but your `into #TMPHEADERID` seems off. You placed in in the subquery where I would expect it in the main query. (You can change `UNION` to `UNION ALL` in the new query by the way. That may spare the DBMS some work.)

Answer (score 0):

```
 select HEADER_ID, max(Actual_Shipment_Date) as Actual_Shipment_Date FROM 
     (SELECT HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date
                FROM HEADERINFO
                UNION
                SELECT HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date
                FROM HEADERINFO2) qry 
        group by HEADER_ID
```

Do you mean this?

Comment: Yes similar but when i am trying the above query with the below it gives error. can you please help:    select HEADER_ID, max(Actual_Shipment_Date) as Actual_Shipment_Date( SELECT
  HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date
 INTO 
  #TMPHEADERID
 FROM
  #HEADERINFO

 UNION

 SELECT
  HEADER_ID,Actual_Shipment_Date
 FROM
  #HEADERINFO2) qry  group by HEADER_ID

Comment: Get rid of the select into

Answer (score 0):

The query given below will give you the max shipment date, grouped by the header id.

```
    SELECT HEADER_ID,Max(Actual_Shipment_Date) as 'Max Shipment Date'
    FROM dbo.HEADERINFO t1
    group by t1.HEADER_ID
    UNION
    SELECT HEADER_ID,Max(Actual_Shipment_Date) as   'Max Shipment Date'
    FROM dbo.HEADERINFO2 t2
    group by t2.HEADER_ID
```

note: t1, t2 referes to table 1 and table 2 respectively.

Comment: Hi Joseph,
When i am trying to run the below query it gives the error as:
Column '#HEADERINFO.HEADER_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not 
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT
  HEADER_ID, max(Actual_Shipment_Date) as [Actual_Shipment_Date]
 INTO 
  #TMPHEADERID
 FROM
  #HEADERINFO
  group by #HEADERINFO.ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DATE

 UNION

 SELECT
  HEADER_ID,max(Actual_Shipment_Date) as [Actual_Shipment_Date]
 FROM
  #HEADERINFO2 
  group by #HEADERINFO2.ACTUAL_SHIPMENT_DATE

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
     SELECT HEADER_ID
    ,max(Actual_Shipment_Date) Shipment_Date
FROM (
    SELECT HEADER_ID
        ,Actual_Shipment_Date
    FROM HEADERINFO

    UNION ALL

    SELECT HEADER_ID
        ,Actual_Shipment_Date
    FROM HEADERINFO2
    ) t4
GROUP BY HEADER_ID
```